# Data export & import(8i -> 10g) and ORA-01461 error

Tags: oracle

Good morning!

I need to move data from Oracle 8i(Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.6.0.0) to Oracle 10g(Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bi).

Each `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is `KO16KSC5601`(8i) and `UTF8`(10g).

I exported data as a Excel file and tried to import it. But I faced `ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column` in "some" data.

It seems that this error occured in a `varchar2(4000)` column. Because it was successfully imported after I shorten the data of `varchar2(4000)` column into few bytes like `"abcde"`.

Can different charset cause a different length of data?..
Please help me out.

Always, thank you.

--For more, I'm using SQLGate which can access both 8i, 10g version(as far as I know).
And of course, I tried export data other formats(dbf, txt, csv, sql, mbd), but they were worse.
dbf, txt, csv made errors on every record. It says some column has no value, but they apprently hava values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, UTF8 is a multi-byte character set. That means some characters are made up of up to 4 bytes of data. KO16KSC5601 is the Korean single byte character set so a character can only consist of a single byte.

Most (all ?) Korean characters will be outside the basic 0-127 positions for the UTF8 characterset, so I'd expect a considerable increase in data size. Look at the [VSIZE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions213.htm) function and use it on some sample data to get an idea of the increases in your situation.

Comment: UTF-8 ist not a character set! Unicode is a character set. UTF-8 is just a possible multi-byte character *enconding*.